# Dynamodb projection by map contents

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

my dynamodb table contains items like this

[image: data screenshot]

I know i can use a projection like:

```
        proj := expression.NamesList(expression.Name("key_Ravenna"))
```

to filter my results by key, but how can I filter by contents of the maps?
e.G. "WHERE LatD == 41"

Appreciate the help, just started migrating my mongodb application to dynamodb

Greetings H.Molnar

Answer (score 1):

You can access nested elements such as Maps using 'dot' notation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html#Expressions.Attributes.NestedAttributes

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name YOURTABLE --filter-expression 'key_Reading.Data.LatD = :val' --expression-attribute-values '{":val":{"S":"41"}}'
```

I've used a scan as an example, which searches across across every item in your table, but you might want a query, only searches across one partition key.

Comment: OK, thank you. Is it possible to get the item from my post but it only returns "key_Reading" because LatD=41 ? Like a projection would work, but i don't know whitch key to project from the begining

Comment: Do you want to pass in the attribute name and/or value as a variable? You can just use the name of the variable, rather than a literal like "41.